# renderContents in beautifulsoup (python)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

The code I'm trying to get working is:

```
h = str(heading)
# '<h1>Heading</h1>'
heading.renderContents()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
print h.renderContents()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'renderContents'
```

Any ideas?

I have a string with html tags and i need to clean it if there is a different way of doing that please suggest it.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message and your code sample don't line up. You say you're calling:

```
heading.renderContents()
```

But your error message says you're calling:

```
print h.renderContents()
```

Which suggests that perhaps you have a bug in your code, trying to call `renderContents()` on a string object that doesn't define that method.

In any case, it would help if you checked what type of object `heading` is to make sure it's really a BeautifulSoup instance. This works for me with BeautifulSoup 3.2.0:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
heading = BeautifulSoup('<h1>heading</h1>')
repr(heading)
# '<h1>heading</h1>'
print heading.renderContents()
# <h1>heading</h1>
print str(heading)
# '<h1>heading</h1>'
h = str(heading)
print h
# <h1>heading</h1>
```